# WPF converter namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I have a problem in `WPF` `Converter` `namespace`.
Below is the description :
"**The name does not exist in the namespace**" for the local:BoolToColor.

**XAML** :

```
<Window x:Class="TFE_WPF.View.FicheClient"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TFE_WPF.View"
        Title="FicheClient" Height="588" Width="663">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BoolToColor x:Key="SColor"></local:BoolToColor>
    </Window.Resources>
```

**Code Behind XAML :**

```
namespace TFE_WPF.View
{
    public partial class FicheClient : Window
    {
        public FicheClient()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new FicheClientViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class BoolToColor : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GreenYellow) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkRed);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the issue with this approach of code? I cleaned the solution and rebuild it but encountered same error.

Comment: Does your project build? I have come across this issue when there is error and the project does not compile.

Comment: did you also try cleaning and rebuilding the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You project which contains the namespace `TFE_WPF.View` is not building and that is why you are getting this error. Fix the issue which is failing your build. Then you will get rid of that error.